# xfwm4 : Center new windows

Tags: debian, xfce, window-manager

I've just installed Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) with xfce gui.

How can I get newly opened windows to open centered on the display. Now they either snap to already opened windows, or open top/bottom left/right:

[image]

I've set "At the centre of the screen" in Window Manager Tweaks:

[image]

Comment: the first image shows the placement of top left corner of the window to be near the center of the screen ... try opening a much smaller window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [xfwm4's faq](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/faq) :

> The Xfce Window Manager has a feature called smart placement which can
> be adjusted based on the window size. Basically it will automatically
> center windows that are below a certain size and once they get bigger
> than that, new windows will try to be arranged automatically in the
> best place to have coverage. You can adjust the minimum size setting
> under Settings → Window Manager Tweaks → Placement.

As shown on your first image, the window's position appears arranged automatically. Which consequently indicates that it's size is bigger than the  minimum defined by the position of the slider in the Placement tab of the tweaks.

Moving the slide to the right should enable systematic centering of larger windows.

---

Since, as Xen2050 asserted in comments, the settings are everything but intuitive and [xfce official documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/wmtweaks) is close to inexistent (limited to some screenshot), we need to [dig into the code](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/-/blob/master/src/placement.c?ref_type=heads) for understanding how settings are taken into account. From line 911 in placement.c :

```
if ((screen_info->params->placement_ratio >= 100) ||
    (100 * frameExtentWidth(c) * frameExtentHeight(c)) <
        (screen_info->params->placement_ratio * full.width * full.height))
{
    if (screen_info->params->placement_mode == PLACE_MOUSE){
        mousePlacement (c, full.x, full.y, full.width, full.height, msx, msy);
    else
        centerPlacement (c, full.x, full.y, full.width, full.height);
}
else if ((frameExtentWidth(c) >= full.width) && (frameExtentHeight(c) >= full.height))
    centerPlacement (c, full.x, full.y, full.width, full.height);
else
    smartPlacement (c, full.x, full.y, full.width, full.height);
```

From what we understand that user chosen default preferences will only be honored if the placement_ratio (understand the number represented by the position of the slider) is greater or equal to 100 (understand at its rightmost position) or if the the window is smaller than the given ratio of the available screen area.

If the window is larger than the screen area, it will be arbitrarily centered and in any other case… *smartly positioned*…

Comment: Strange they would have the slider option that can render the next "center or under mouse pointer" option ineffective. Hope they change that and make it clear how it works.

Comment: I fully agree with you @Xen2050 . Even worse :  some themes are known to arbitrarily set the value of the ratio represented by the slider… without notice. I updated my answer expecting to make things clearer thanks to the source code.